# Android SetNewPassword Intent returning RESULT_FIRST_USER

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am starting up the `ActionSetNewPassword` action via an `Intent`. On return I am watching for `OK` and running some code or `CANCEL` and closing.

This was working fine but now I am being returned `RESULT_FIRST_USER` rather than `OK` when I successfully deal with the action.

Why would I be now being passed back `RESULT_FIRST_USER`? 
What is that result code supposed to tell me?

**EDIT**

I am using Xamarin and MVVMCross to start the activity. This has been all working fine I would just like to know under what circumstances Android would send back `RESULT_FIRST_USER`

```
 Intent actionSetNewPasswordIntent =
       new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ActionSetNewPassword);

 this.context.StartActivityForResult(
                 actionSetNewPasswordIntent, 
                 20);
```

In the Activity I am listening for the return like so

```
if (requestCode == 20)
{
    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        if (this.spm.CheckCompliance() != SecurityPolicyCompliance.Compliant)
        {
            // This should not happen as by now we have applied for Device Admin 
            // and sent them to SetNewPassword where they have not cancelled
            this.Finish();
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
    {
        // User backed away from changing password.
        this.Finish();
    }
}
else
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can please provide the code how you passback the values between the 2 activities ?

Comment: I am deliberately left it out so as not to cloud the question but I realise that is a bit unfair. I am using Xamarin and MVVMCross to start it. I as hoping that someone could just explain what the RESULT_FIRST_USER is for. I will edit the question

Comment: this is how you start the other activity but How are you doing the response back? can you show so I can try to help.

Comment: Now updated. Sorry for the delay I have been on away

Comment: OK no problem you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android

Comment: I don't see how that question helps me